# Can't recover the Gmail username to access my Android phone

Tags: gmail

My son has a BlackBerry which has pattern password. His younger brother has pressed it too many times and it is now locked. It is asking for his Gmail username but he does not know it. He has never used the email and did not set up a recovery email address. None of the guidance I can find tells me what to do.

How can I find his username?

Comment: Tell us what you've already tried (something like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U053D4gg27Q). Note that you may have to factory reset the phone.

Comment: Factory Reset seems like the only way to go